# What does colon mean in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am studying XLST and I encounter the following code:

```
  <xsl:template match="start">
    <heading>From <xsl:value-of select="@loc"/>:</heading>
  </xsl:template>
```

So I am wondering what does the : mean in the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I am wondering what does the : mean in the second line.

If you mean the `:` just before the `</heading>` closing tag, it doesn't mean anything. It's [literal text](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Creating-Text) - just like the string `From` after the  `<heading>` opening tag is.